# Removing Duplicates while doing concatinate using XSLT2.0

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have one requirement that i need to Concat the "F_NAME:S_Name:L_Name" by grouping them with Age element. But while concatenating i must exclude
the duplicates.

I used for-each-group and then tried the Concat function, the code is given below.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <ns0:Parent>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="/ns0:Parent/ns0:child" group-by="ns0:Age">
        <ns0:child>
          <ns0:F_Name>
            <xsl:value-of separator=";" select="current-group()/concat(ns0:S_Name,':',ns0:F_NAME,':',ns0:L_Name)"/>

          </ns0:F_Name>
        </ns0:child>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </ns0:Parent>
  </xsl:template>
```

## I/P:

```
<Parent>
    <child>
        <F_NAME> Alex </F_NAME>
        <S_Name> Mark <S_Name>
        <L_Name> Jay </L_Name>
        <Age> 35 </Age>
    </child>
    <child>
        <F_NAME> Marie </F_NAME>
        <S_Name> Julie <S_Name>
        <L_Name> Kane </L_Name>
        <Age> 35 </Age>
    </child>
    <child>
        <F_NAME> Alex </F_NAME>
        <S_Name> Mark <S_Name>
        <L_Name> Jay </L_Name>
        <Age> 35 </Age>
    </child>
</Parent>
```

## Actual Output:

```
<Parent>
    <Child>
        <Age>35</Age>
        <F_Name>Alex:Mark:Jay;Marie:Julie:Kane;Alex:Mark:Jay</F_NAME>
    </Child>
</Parent>
```

## Expected Output:

```
<Parent>
    <Child>
        <Age>35</Age>
        <F_Name>Alex:Mark:Jay;Marie:Julie:Kane</F_NAME>
    </Child>
</Parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you use `distinct-values(current-group()/concat(ns0:S_Name,':',ns0:F_NAME,':',ns0:L_Name))` instead of `current-group()/concat(ns0:S_Name,':',ns0:F_NAME,':',ns0:L_Name)`, then you should get unique names.

Comment: Perfect!! Worked as expected, Thanks a lot Martin.